# Overriding textColorPrimary,textColorSecondary for a fragment or ViewGroup or Widgets - AppCompact

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-appcompat, android-theme

In AppCompact we use attributes like colorPrimary, colorPrimaryDark, colorAccent, textColorPrimary for App Themes.

I would like to know can we Override or change these Colors to different colors in a fragment or a ViewGroup. Like, can we change these colors for only NavigationView or can we change these colors only for a ExpandableListView in a Fragment.

**EDIT:**
I tried overriding with different Style, but it is not Overriding

```
<style name="DarkText" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/black</item>

    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/black</item>
</style>

<ExpandableListView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/DarkText"
    android:groupIndicator="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
```

**My ChildVeiw in Adapter:**

```
final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }

    TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

    txtListChild.setText(childText);
```

**Please Note:** I dont want to Change Color of the text using `txtListChild.setTextColor` or android:textColor="@color/black" in my R.layout.list_item

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that like this

```
<ExpandableListView
    android:theme="@style/AnotherTheme"/>
```

Edit:

Change the line of inflate to this, replace `parent` if needed

```
convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
```

Comment: that is not Overriding Previous Theme that is the whole reason I posted here

Comment: also, it could depends on whether you are inflating the child of the ListView correctly

Comment: Please look carefully `android:textColorPrimary` -> `textColorPrimary`, try remove the `android:`

Comment: I think we cant remove `android:` for `textColorPrimary` in AppCompat theme. It was unable to find the attribute. `No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'textColorPrimary'.` Can you tell me the difference between `android:textColorPrimary` and `textColorPrimary`

Comment: can you add the code where you inflate children for ExpandableListView?

Answer (score 0):

Try Overriding a getview() in array adapter

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), 
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mStringList) {
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        return view;
    }
};
```

Comment: Changing the Color for a ViewGroup Dynamically is not a problem, I am asking can we Override it completely. I dont want to change it every where using code.